# How to check whether any html tags entered is closed or not in textarea using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my project i'm using commenting system, where i want the user can use html special chars, if they enter html char
 **For Example :-** 
`<a href="#">Click Here` 
 in above example i didn't close `a tag` if user enter invalid html tags as i shown in example i want to raise exception or alert of "html tags not closeed". How to do it?

Comment: Hi I exactly dont know how to do that but there is a plugin which does very close thing to what you have asked... kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/L6L2p3oc/1/  plugin page http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

Comment: @RRR : what if i didn't press enter

Comment: Hi its upto you when you want to run the plugin code just for demo purpose i was calling the plugin funtion on enter key press... here i have changed it a bit kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/L6L2p3oc/3/  (now it works as soon as you close the html tag